# Testing: Cancelling flow with infinite emissions

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, kotlin-coroutines, turbine

Having some issues testing a flow that emits infinite messages:

```
Class:
class MessageManager(
    dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
) {
    private val messageFlow = flow {
        while (true) {
            delay(60_000)  // Emit every minute
            try {
                val messages = service.getMessages().await()
                emit(messages)
            } catch (error: Exception) {
                Log.e("Messages", "Error fetching messages: $error")
            }
        }
    }.flowOn(dispatcher)
        .shareIn(scope, SharingStarted.Lazily, 1)

    val messages: StateFlow<List<Message>> = messageFlow.stateIn(
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main),
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
        emptyList()
    )
}
```

Test:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MessageManagerTest {

    private val testScheduler = TestCoroutineScheduler()
    private val application: Application = mockk(relaxed = true)
    private val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher(testScheduler)
    private val mockMessages = listOf(Message("id1", "Test message 1", listOf("mock")))

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun `messages emits expected data`() = runTest {
        // Initialize BroadcastManager
        val messageManager = MessageManager(application, testDispatcher)

        // Test the messages flow with Turbine
        messageManager.messages.test {
            // Assert initial state
            assertTrue(awaitItem().isEmpty())

            // Advance time and assert next emission
            advanceTimeBy(60_000)

            assertEquals(mockMessages, awaitItem())

            cancelAndIgnoreRemainingEvents()
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation is that I should only receive one emitted list of messages before the remaning events gets cancelled, but that is not the case. Currently the messageFlow never stops emitting messages. Am I missing something obvious here?